# New hard drive is read-only and root-only access, how can I get full access to it?

Tags: partitioning, permissions, 16.04, hard-drive

I'm very new to this and I've been at trying to fix this problem for about two hours to no avail.

I just finished getting my new computer put together and installed a new 2TB Seagate hard drive as a secondary drive (my boot drive has no problems at all). I have it formatted into two petitions, one in ext4 through GParted. I want to use this partition to store extra files and programs (specifically games and CAD stuff). I went to make a steam library folder in it and found that it's read only. It is at /dev/sda1

I first attempted to reformat it to no avail. I looked around for some help (most of what I found related to external storage) and tried a few things through the terminal to change the owner.

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/
```

Returned "only root can do that."

I'm stuck past here, I've tried a couple other things I can't hunt down now, but every attempt gives an access problem to me. How can I change this and regain access? Are there more effective ways to map/install this drive for this purpose to avoid this problem in the future? Thank you!

Comment: This is helpful https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

Comment: Thanks for your input, unfortunately, that didn't change this for me... The partition is mounted at '/media/me/Files', and using 'chown' still didn't change it from root ownership. I tried is at a variety of levels, but it is still persistently only-root.

Comment: Okay, actually that totally worked. It took closing everything and opening a new terminal session, but it worked. If you have any idea what would have changed in doing that I would really love to know! Now putting in `ls -l` and that mount point gives two returns `drwx------ 2 root root ... ` and `drwxrwxr-x 3 me me ... SteamLibrary` I'm happy it works, but what changed in just doing that? Did the directories just get refreshed for every program? Thank you again!

Comment: since it worked I posted it as an answer. If it help you please accept the answer @SpacePirateRob

Comment: Just got to that sorry, been out for most of the weekend. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your partition mounted? Find that, open a terminal, and change to the directory that contains it. Then type the command `ls -l`. This will show you who owns the mount point and therefore all the files under it. If it's root, you can change it so that you own it by typing `sudo chown [yourusername]:[yourusername] [the mountpoint]` It will ask you for your password, type it in, you will not see anything as you type. This has helped me in similar situations.